# Swap even and odd page margin in document class book

Tags: margins

I am writing a book and I would like to swap the even and odd page margins without changing the page numbers. I am using document class book.

I know that by default the book class sets the margin of the odd pages on the right side but I want to reverse this.

This is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Auxiliary Results}
\section{Introduction}
Much of the special necessary mathe......
\end{document}
```

And this is what i get as the first page.

[image: Page 1]

I want to open every chapter on the right-side page. And with the margin like the one shown in the image, I would end up having a large margin on the right side and no margin on the left after binding the book.

I know that some similar questions might be out there but I didn't find anything appropriate to my situation.

Comment: Really? You found nothing appropriate? Nothing about `geometry`? `\usepackage[hmarginratio=3:2]` would reverse the margins (`2:3` is the default ratio used by `geometry` when `twoside` is active, as is default for the `book` class).

Comment: Note that having a large margin on the outer edge is the usual typographic default and implemented intentionally in book class. Are you sure you want to reverse centuries old practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`geometry` gives you a great deal of easy-to-use control over page layout. This is the default layout used by the package for `book`:

[image: Default layout]

Here is the effect of inverting the ratio of the inner to outer margin:

[image: Switch margin ratios]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe, hmarginratio=3:2]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Auxiliary Results}
\section{Introduction}
\kant[1-5]

\end{document}
```

For more complete control, see the details in the package documentation. You may wish to specify margins etc. explicitly. Also, don't forget to remove `showframe` to get rid of the frames showing the page layout!

Answer (score 2):

What you intend to do will look really ugly in a binded book,  please read the first chapter of the koma script documentation about typography.

The option you need is not too invert the margins.  Just add an appropriate binding correction with the option

```
 BCOR=space
```

E. G.

```
 BCOR=12mm
```